# Do your action providers have only string parameter types?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In asp.net mvc, should I make my parameters in my action methods string or can I have them as Integers?

(say for page numbers)

Comment: Page numbers should be integers, but you can have any type you want as an action method parameter (as long as you bind them correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page numbers should be integers, not strings. ASP.NET MVC will convert them appropiately (as long as they are actually integers).

And as I said in my comment to your question (and [also noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877979/do-your-action-providers-have-only-string-parameter-types/878006#878006) by MasterMind), you can have any type as parameter to your action method.

Answer (score 1):

You can have them of different types, even of your custom defined classes.